# How to change background and foreground color of a disabled SwiftUI TextField on macOS

Tags: swiftui

I need to make enabled and disabled TextFields looks like the same, instead they looks like in this way:

[image]

Apparently, SwiftUI doesn't provide any modifier for that.

I am thinking to overlay a Text when the TextField is disabled but I don't like it much and likely I would have to struggle with sizes, alignments and stuff like that.

Any better suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `enabled` modifier, try using `allowsHitTesting()`

`allowsHitTesting` with `false` value won't change the color of textfield, but will block any touches thus making it disabled for user.

```
Text(messageObj.title)
   .frame(alignment: .center)
   .font(.system(size: 16.0))
   .allowsHitTesting(false)
```